# Recursive file and directory operations

Tags: bash, shell-script, zsh

I'm trying to recursively preform a series of operations on many directories containing files.  In each directory I want to create 2 directories and move some of the files into each.

For instance, my directory structure looks like this ...

```
   root --
     subdirectory1 --
         file_a1_a.tif
         file_a2_a.tif
         file_a1_b.tif
         file_a2_b.tif
     subdirectory2 --
         file_b1_a.tif
         file_b2_a.tif
         file_b1_b.tif
         file_b2_b.tif
```

I'd like to reorganize the files to be like this ...

```
   root --
     subdirectory1 --
         subdirectory_a --
             file_a1_a.tif
             file_a2_a.tif
         subdirectory_b --
             file_a1_b.tif
             file_a2_b.tif
     subdirectory2 --
         subdirectory_a --
             file_b1_a.tif
             file_b2_a.tif
         subdirectory_b --
             file_b1_b.tif
             file_b2_b.tif
```

I'm doing the following but it only seems to work in the top level directory.

```
find . -type d -execdir bash -c "mkdir -p subdirectory_a && mkdir -p subdirectory_b && mv *_a.tif subdirectory_a 2>/dev/null && mv *_b.tif subdirectory_b 2>/dev/null" \;
```

Any help would be greatly apprecited

Answer (score 2):

Since `root` has only children and not grandchildren, you can run this from `root` directory:

```
subA='subdirectory_a'
subB='subdirectory_b'
for d in */; do
    mkdir -p "$d$subA" "$d$subB"
    mv "$d"*_a.tif "$d$subA"
    mv "$d"*_b.tif "$d$subB"
done
```

`$d` expands to `subdirectory1/` and `subdirectory2/` because of the glob on the for loop, `*/`, which matches only immediate subdirectories. The corresponding `root` grandchildren are created with `mkdir` (the `-p` is there just so that it does not complain if they already exist), and then globbing is used again to move the files to grandchildren.

Notice that globs should be unquoted if the shell is to expand them. That is why `mv "$d"*_a.tif "$d$subA"` is correct but `mv "$d*_a.tif" "$d$subA"` would be incorrect.

Comment: Very nice ! For a small amount of files  in each subdirectory `$d` this will work beautifully. +1'ed

Comment: I see how this works and it answers my question as asked.  Will this no work with grandchildren of root? My real application does have grandchildren and great-grandchildren in some cases.

Comment: Many thanks @SergiyKolodyazhnyy for your words. agf1997, it does not work with grandchilden. I'm sorry, but your sample did not provide one :/

Comment: It does work with "grandchildren". As in, the grandchildren would be ignored (unless they happened to be pre-existing directories `subdirectory_a` and `subdirectory_b`). It is unclear what @agf1997 means by "work".

Comment: @Kusalananda Indeed! Except if there is a directory grandchild named with something like `file_a3_b.tif`, in which case it matches the glob pattern and will also be moved.

Answer (score 2):

The command you've posted in the question

```
find . -type d -execdir bash -c "mkdir -p subdirectory_a && mkdir -p subdirectory_b && mv *_a.tif subdirectory_a 2>/dev/null && mv *_b.tif subdirectory_b 2>/dev/null" \;
```

behaves correctly ( that is , it does what it is supposed to do ). But what it spells out is not what you want.

The `-execdir` argument operates such that "...the specified command is run from the
 subdirectory containing the matched file," (source, [find(1)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) )

That is to say, when your current working directly is `root` and the command locates `subdirectory1` it will not descend there as you expect. The `subdirectory1` which matches `-type d` was found when `find` was inside `root`, hence it will stay there and execute the `mkdir` command specified from there. Naturally, there is no files inside `root`, hence nothing will be moved around, but also note that `mkdir -p` won't produce an error, as specified by the [mkdir(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mkdir) : "no error if existing".

---

So how do we make this match what you want? Let's assume the same structure you've posted

```
$ tree /tmp/root
/tmp/root
├── subdir1
│   ├── file_a1_a.tif
│   ├── file_a1_b.tif
│   ├── file_a2_a.tif
│   └── file_a2_b.tif
└── subdir2
    ├── file_b1_a.tif
    ├── file_b1_b.tif
    ├── file_b2_a.tif
    └── file_b2_b.tif
```

I'd suggest making it a three-step process. There is no need to make a one single command do all the work. Focus on the desired result rather than "code golf". So make the directories first

```
$ find /tmp/root -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec bash -c 'mkdir ${1}/subdirectory_{a,b}' sh  {} \;
$ tree
.
├── subdir1
│   ├── file_a1_a.tif
│   ├── file_a1_b.tif
│   ├── file_a2_a.tif
│   ├── file_a2_b.tif
│   ├── subdirectory_a
│   └── subdirectory_b
└── subdir2
    ├── file_b1_a.tif
    ├── file_b1_b.tif
    ├── file_b2_a.tif
    ├── file_b2_b.tif
    ├── subdirectory_a
    └── subdirectory_b

6 directories, 8 files
```

And then find regular files at specific level in directory tree and move them. Now we can use `-execdir` to achieve exactly what we want

```
$ find /tmp/root -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type f -execdir bash -c 'case ${1} in *a.tif) echo cp ${1} ./subdirectory_a ;; *b.tif) echo cp ${1} subdirectory_b ;; esac' sh {} \;
cp ./file_b2_b.tif subdirectory_b
cp ./file_b2_a.tif ./subdirectory_a
cp ./file_b1_a.tif ./subdirectory_a
cp ./file_b1_b.tif subdirectory_b
cp ./file_a1_b.tif subdirectory_b
cp ./file_a1_a.tif ./subdirectory_a
cp ./file_a2_b.tif subdirectory_b
cp ./file_a2_a.tif ./subdirectory_a
```

Note that in this case, I use echo before moving to ensure everything behaves properly , and no actual moving is done. So if we remove `echo`, this will behave correctly:

```
$ find /tmp/root -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type f -execdir bash -c 'case ${1} in *a.tif) cp ${1} ./subdirectory_a ;; *b.tif) cp ${1} subdirectory_b ;; esac' sh {} \;
$ tree /tmp/root
/tmp/root
├── subdir1
│   ├── file_a1_a.tif
│   ├── file_a1_b.tif
│   ├── file_a2_a.tif
│   ├── file_a2_b.tif
│   ├── subdirectory_a
│   │   ├── file_a1_a.tif
│   │   └── file_a2_a.tif
│   └── subdirectory_b
│       ├── file_a1_b.tif
│       └── file_a2_b.tif
└── subdir2
    ├── file_b1_a.tif
    ├── file_b1_b.tif
    ├── file_b2_a.tif
    ├── file_b2_b.tif
    ├── subdirectory_a
    │   ├── file_b1_a.tif
    │   └── file_b2_a.tif
    └── subdirectory_b
        ├── file_b1_b.tif
        └── file_b2_b.tif

6 directories, 16 files
```

Note of course that this uses copying to avoid data loss. We can further clean up  and in the end - we get the desired directory tree structure.

```
$ find /tmp/root -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type f -delete
$ tree 
.
├── subdir1
│   ├── subdirectory_a
│   │   ├── file_a1_a.tif
│   │   └── file_a2_a.tif
│   └── subdirectory_b
│       ├── file_a1_b.tif
│       └── file_a2_b.tif
└── subdir2
    ├── subdirectory_a
    │   ├── file_b1_a.tif
    │   └── file_b2_a.tif
    └── subdirectory_b
        ├── file_b1_b.tif
        └── file_b2_b.tif

6 directories, 8 files
```

In conclusion what we've done can be expressed as one single script

```
find /tmp/root -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec bash -c 'mkdir ${1}/subdirectory_{a,b}' sh  {} \; &&
find /tmp/root -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type f -execdir bash -c 'case ${1} in *a.tif) cp ${1} ./subdirectory_a ;; *b.tif) cp ${1} subdirectory_b ;; esac' sh {} \; &&
find /tmp/root -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type f -delete
```

Of course, steps 2 and 3 can be condensed into one if we use `mv` instead of `cp`, but I would rather err on the side of caution than to risk data loss.

Comment: This is a wonderful answer, Sergiy. You go step by step so that anyone here can follow the chain of thought, especially useful to newcomers. Thanks for that, +1 too.

Answer (score 1):

Your command, when run inside of the `root` directory, is going to create `subdirectoy_a` and `subdirectory_b` at the top level alongside `subdirectory1` and `subdirectory2` and then move all of the files ending in `a.tiff` into `subdirectory1` and all of the files ending in `b.tiff` into `subdirectory_b` which isn't what you want. This would be easier for you to troubleshoot if you weren't redirecting the errors to `/dev/null` and could actually see them. You also don't need the `-p` option with `mkdir` because the parent directories already exist.

Instead of what you have, run this from inside of `root` (or whatever the directory is actually called).

```
mkdir subdirectory1/subdirectory_a subdirectory1/subdirectory_b subdirectory2/subdirectory_a subdirectory2/subdirectory_b && mv subdirectory1/file_a*a*  subdirectory1/subdirectory_a && mv subdirectory1/file_a*b*  subdirectory1/subdirectory_b && mv subdirectory2/file_b*a*  subdirectory2/subdirectory_a && mv subdirectory2/file_b*b*  subdirectory2/subdirectory_b
```

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
cd root || exit
subdirs=(*(-/))
mkdir -p -- $^subdirs/subdirectory_{a,b} || exit
autoload -Uz zmv
zmv '(*/)*_(a|b).tif' '${1}subdirectory_$2/$f:t'
```

If it needs to be *recursive* as your question says (but your sample doesn't suggest), that is if you also need that to be done in `subdir1/subsubdir1` and so on, replace the `*`s in `*(-/)` and `(*/)` above with `**`.

If there are zillions of files and speed is a concern, run `zmodload zsh/files` for `mkdir` and `mv` (called by `zmv`) to become zsh builtins.

For a *dry-run* where `zmv` only shows you what it *would* do, add a `-n` option.

If you only want the `subdirectory_a` and `subdirectory_b` to be created in directories that do contain some `*_a.tif` and `*_b.tif` respectively, you could take this other approach:

```
mkmv() { mkdir -p -- $2:h && mv -- "$@"; }
zmv -P mkmv '(**/)*_(a|b).tif' '${1}subdirectory_$2/$f:t'
```

(that one would also move `tif` files located in the `root` itself).